# Triangle related coordinate geometry question

Tags: coordinate-systems

> Given triangle $\triangle ABC$ , with $AB=AC$ and 2 times(length of
>   inradius) which is equal to the length of exradius of excirle opposite
>   vertex $A$. Setup the coordinate system in the plane of triangle
>   $\triangle ABC$ as follow:   Origin at vertex $B$, positive X-axis
>   along $BC$ and positive Y-axis on the $A$ side of $BC$. Find the
>   equations of the incircle , excircles and circumcircle.

Also this question is related to the incenter excenter configuration of triangle.I would like to get some help to solve the above question.

Comment: it was not that i did not accept the answers but i was really not knowing what we should do to show that i have accepted the answer....really sorry for that

Comment: You can find the equation of incircle [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Here is a diagram of the construction described above.

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

There is no absolute scale given in the problem, so lets set the inradius of $\triangle ABC$ to be $1$. Since the radius of the excircle opposite $A$ is twice that of the incircle, it is $2$. By similar triangles, we have $|AE|=2|AD|$. Furthermore, $|DE|=3$, so $|AD|=3$ and $|AE|=6$.

Everything else should be calculable using similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

In the coordinate system $(B,\vec{BC},\vec{BC'})$ we have $B(0,0)$, $C(1,0)$ and $A\left(\frac 12,a\right)$  where $a=AH$ : height from vertex $A$.
You have to find $a$  using hypothesis and  the rest must be  easy.

Comment: :How did you get the coordinates of vertex B and  vertex C?

Comment: "the rest must be easy", but it *is not*.

Comment: : *How did you get the coordinates of vertex A and vertex C?

Comment: @ meg_1977 and Gigili : Since geometric properties do not change by changing the unit of reference, we can choose BC for the unit, then coordinates of $C$ are $1$ and $0$.The abscissa of  $A$  is  $\frac 12$ and  it's  ordinate  is $a=AH$ where $H$   is  the middle  of  $[BC]$  who  can be  calculated  by  using  radius hypothésis.